# Handling static files with Django / lighttpd

Tags: django, lighttpd

I know that there is already a question (actually some more) about this, but the answers to them didn't help me out very much, as I am pretty new to lighttpd.

I have one folder which contains .pdf-files. When doing a HttpResponseRedirect to the locations of one of those .pdf-files, the user should be able to download the .pdf file (or view it in the browser). Right now, Django just redirects to my "home" html page, without showing any pdf-file.

Somehow, I will have to tell lighttpd that Django shouldn't handle this directory anymore.
Is this the only thing I need to do? If yes, how should i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you see the section "[lighttpd setup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#lighttpd-setup)" in the Django docs? Using *alias.url* an *url.rewrite-once* you can route the requests to you app or a folder serving files:

```
alias.url = (
    "/pdfs" => "/path/to/my/pdfs",
)

url.rewrite-once = (
    "^(/pdfs.*)$" => "$1",
    "^(/.*)$" => "/mysite.fcgi$1",
)
```

Comment: does this also work for subfolders of "/pdfs"?

btw., thanks for your answer. 
When i go to "/path/to/my/pdfs" (other path for me, of course), django returns "Directory indexes are not allowed here.", so it seems it is still handling it.

Comment: What URL do you use? 127.0.0.1:8000/pdfs/file1.pdf or something like this. Are you sure, that the "Directory indexes are not allowed here." message is not from lighttpd? Perhaps you need to enable directory listing with mod_dirlisting (http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModDirlisting)

Comment: the fault was a totally different one, i missed a slash in the argument of HttpResponseRedirect...